# Which kind of CSS adding so that header begins directly at beginning of page?

Tags: html, css

What kind of CSS styling can I add so that my header begins directly on the top of the page? For now there is always some space between the header and the page beginning.

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```css
.page-header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```